# Having a lot of trouble connecting to Cloud SQL Postgres in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have configured by `database.yml` file according to this [guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-ruby-on-rails-cloud-sql-postgres-ruby/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#9) but it always comes back the error:

**Error in Compute Engine**

> PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>           Is the server running locally and accepting
>           connections on Unix domain socket "/cloudsql/[YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I have whitelisted the network of `0.0.0.0/0` and also tried this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-compute-engine) where you install the cloud sql proxy, but still no luck.

**database.yml**

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: databse-name
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  sslca: config/ssl/server-ca.pem
  sslcert: config/ssl/client-cert.pem
  sslkey: config/ssl/client-key.pem
```

Comment: in case, on which environment are your running the app ? (bare-metal, google cloud compute engine instance, other…)

Comment: apologies.. it's running on compute engine

Comment: so... I tried changing the host from this format `"/cloudsql/[YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]/.s.PGSQL.5432"` to use the ip address and it connected... `rails db:migrate` works but it's definitely not a good solution for production.

Comment: humm… do not yes this is probably not the solution, as compute engine might be one of the easiest place to run cloud sql (obviously). Can you `printenv` maybe to check to see if everything is there ?

Comment: Besides that, if cloudsql is running, you might want to remove most of the config (as you'd do in a standard local dev environment)

Comment: Do you get something when you run `psql "host=127.0.0.1 sslmode=disable dbname=<DB_NAME> user=<USER_NAME>"` (bottom of page https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/quickstart-proxy-test). As you can see, there should be no pwd, no ssl, etc… you should be able to connect with the minimum requirements

Comment: Unfortunately I just get this error: `psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Comment: then the proxy could not be running (`ps aux` ?). In case, have you installed the client ? (`sudo apt-get install postgresql-client`)

Comment: oh my gawd. Feeling like a complete idiot. I thought the tutorial was referring to the compute instance instead of the pg instance =.= since there was a link **GO TO THE COMPUTE ENGINE INSTANCES LISTING** above. Everything works now as it should. Cheers!